# Django blocktrans with variable

Tags: django, internationalization, po, django-i18n

I have a template, in which I want to translate a string.

```
{% blocktrans with "www.mywebsite.com" as website_name %}footer-slogan{{ website_name }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

I've generated my po file, in which I've translated the string as follow :

```
msgid "footer-slogan %(website_name)s"
msgstr "This is a test %(website_name)s"
```

On my generated html file, I get this untranslated element :

```
footer-slogan www.mywebsite.com
```

If I remove the variable from the translated string, it works :

```
msgid "footer-slogan %(website_name)s"
msgstr "This is a test"
```

I've even tried to remove the variable from the source translation but keeping the variable in the translated string, the issue is the same :

```
template.html
{% blocktrans with "www.mywebsite.com" as website_name %}footer-slogan{% endblocktrans %}

django.po
msgid "footer-slogan"
msgstr "This is a test %(website_name)s"
```

I'd prefer to be able to set the variable only on the translated string.

What I'm doing wrong on the translated string?

Answer (score 2):

**You can use it this way**:

```
{% blocktrans %} 
    {% with website_name="www.mywebsite.com" %}
        {% trans 'footer-slogan{{ website_name }}' %}
    {% endwith %}   
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested, it's still not working.

Comment: @Fab, There was a `typo` mistake. Try it now and let me know about it.

Comment: I've seen your type previously. Even after correcting it, it doesn't work.

Comment: I've finally find the issue. It was because I was displaying an other language, which wasn't translated yet. And I didn't find in the documentation but for people who are wondering if it's possible to use a variable inside the po file, which is not used in the original translation, it's not possible. It has to be specified.

Comment: It looks like on the view, it's not mandatory to provide the variable inside the translation ID. But in the template it is.

Comment: @Fab, Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: But blocktrans does not allow other block tags in it.

Answer (score 2):

Little late to answer but for other people that come seeking

```
`{% blocktrans with site_name="xyz" %}{{ site_name }} - Your account 
 has been successfully created and activated!{% endblocktrans %}`
```